# List item with Multiple paragraphs and sublists in LibreOffice writer

Tags: libreoffice, list

*Posted as Q&A after I found a solution.*

I sometimes need complex lists, where e.g. a list contains hierarchical sub-items, and mixed with regular paragraphs.

[image: Example using LaTeX]

Using `Shift+Enter` provides only an approximation, as the line break messes up spacing (especially in justified paragraph styles).

How can this behavior be obtained with LibreOffice writer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A similar behavior can be obtained by

1. "Styles > Number List"
2. Use "Backspace" (`←` key) to remove the item number.

```
INPUT                                      OUTPUT
---------------------------------------    -----------------------------------
This is the first item. <ENTER><TAB>        1. This is the first item.
There are some <ENTER>                         1. There are some
sub-items. <ENTER><Shift+TAB><Backspace>       2. sub-items.
At the end a summary is needed. <ENTER>        At the end a summary is needed.
This is another top-level item.             2. This is another top-level item.
```

Note that the indentation of continuation paragraphs will be the same as for automatic line breaks in long text on the first paragraph of an item.

Reproducing the switch to the alphabetic `(a)` style for the nested list would involved modifying the numbering styles (see *Styles (<kbd>F11</kbd>) > "List Styles" tab*).